OrangePi 3 LTS ili9488
I have OrangePi 3 LTS and BTT TFT35 SPI v2.1 with ili9488. I am trying to connect display to OrangePi via SPI, but I dont have ili9488 driver in fbtft folder. When I am building fbtft with ili9488 from GitHub https://github.com/Snitro/fbtft-ili9488, I am getting error. What did I wrong?
Armbian Debian
uname -a
Linux orangepi3-lts 6.6.31-current-sunxi64

FBTFT build error:
root@orangepi3-lts:/lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev# make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.31-current-sunxi64'
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488/fbtft-core.o
/lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488/fbtft-core.c: In function ‘fbtft_framebuffer_alloc’:
/lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488/fbtft-core.c:694:36: error: ‘FBINFO_FLAG_DEFAULT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘FAULT_FLAG_DEFAULT’?
  694 |         info->flags =              FBINFO_FLAG_DEFAULT | FBINFO_VIRTFB;
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                    FAULT_FLAG_DEFAULT
/lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488/fbtft-core.c:694:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488/fbtft-core.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:480: /lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft-ili9488] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.31-current-sunxi64/Makefile:1915: /lib/modules/6.6.31-current-sunxi64/build/drivers/video/fbdev] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.31-current-sunxi64'

sun50i-h6-spi-ili9488-led-always-on.dts
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
        compatible = "xunlong,orangepi-3-lts","allwinner,sun50i-h6";


        fragment@0 {
                target-path = "/aliases";
                __overlay__ {
                        spi0 = "/soc/spi@5010000";
                        spi1 = "/soc/spi@5011000";
                };
        };

        fragment@2 {
               target = <&r_pio>;
                __overlay__ {
                        spi1_cs1_pin: spi1_cs1_pin {
                                pins = "PA8"; /* - real use PL8 but... error in calculate pin number 360!!!!*/
                                function = "gpio_out";
                                output-high;
                        };
                };
        };

        fragment@3 {
                 target = <&spi1>;
                 __overlay__ {
                            pinctrl-names = "default", "default";
                            pinctrl-1 = < &spi1_cs1_pin>;
                            cs-gpios = <0>, <&r_pio 0 8 0>; /* PL8 */

                            status = "okay";
                            debug=<0>;
                            #address-cells = <1>;
                            #size-cells = <0>;
                            spidev@0 {
                                     reg = <0>; /* Chip Select 0 */
                                     compatible = "spidev";
                                     spi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
                                     status = "disabled";
                            };
                            spidev@1 {
                                      reg = <1>; /* Chip Select 1 */
                                      compatible = "spidev";
                                      spi-max-frequency = <12000000>;
                                      status = "disabled";
                            };
                 };
        };

  fragment@4 {
    target = <&pio>;
    __overlay__ {
      ili9486_pins: ili9486_pins {
        pins = "PD21", "PD16"; /*RESET, DC_RS*/
        function = "gpio_out", "gpio_out" ;
      };
    };
  };
        fragment@5 {
                target = <&spi1>;
                __overlay__ {
                        /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        cs-gpios = <0>, <&r_pio 0 8 0>; /* PL8 */
                        status = "okay";

                        ili9486: ili9486@0 {
                                compatible = "ilitek,ili9486";
                                spi-max-frequency = <24000000>;
                                reg = <0>;
                                pinctrl-names = "default";
                                pinctrl-0 = <&ili9486_pins>;
                                        status = "okay";
                                debug=<0>;
                                txbuflen = <32768>;
                                rotate = <90>;
                                bgr = <0>;
                                fps = <60>;
                                buswidth = <8>;
                                regwidth = <16>;
                                reset-gpios = <&pio 3 21 0>; /*RST= PD21 */
                                dc-gpios = <&pio 3 16 0>; /*LCD_RS PD16 */
                                init = < 0x10000f1 0x36 0x04 0x00 0x3c 0x0f 0x8f 
                                0x10000f2 0x18 0xa3 0x12 0x02 0xb2 0x12 0xff 0x10 0x00 
                                0x10000f8 0x21 0x04 
                                0x10000f9 0x00 0x08 
                                0x1000036 0x08 
                                0x10000b4 0x00 
                                0x10000c1 0x41 
                                0x10000c5 0x00 0x91 0x80 0x00 
                                0x10000e0 0x0f 0x1f 0x1c 0x0c 0x0f 0x08 0x48 0x98 0x37 0x0a 0x13 0x04 0x11 0x0d 0x00 
                                0x10000e1 0x0f 0x32 0x2e 0x0b 0x0d 0x05 0x47 0x75 0x37 0x06 0x10 0x03 0x24 0x20 0x00 
                                0x100003a 0x55 
                                0x1000011 
                                0x1000036 0x28 
                                0x20000ff 
                                0x1000029 >;
                        };
                };
        };
};



The fbtft driver is already in your kernel sources, what you need is to forward-port the actual driver, which is really small.

I'm use overlay. I'm found dts file for ili9486 tft display and copy it. With command armbian-add-overlay im compile it into dtb and add to armbianBoot.txt, this file work correctly and i see fb0 in /dev but display is white. When I try to change ili9486 to ili9488 in this file, i dont see fb0 in /dev and dmesg | grep ili9488 is empty.

@0andriy I'm add overlay dts file

Because your display is different. There is a small driver on top of fbtft that supports your panel, but that one wasn’t added to the vanilla kernel. You need to forward-port it. Download source code for the kernel you use, add that file and respective Makefile and Kconfig changes, and recompile that fbtft module.

@0andriy oh thanks for your answer. Sorry I am newbie, would be nice any guide/manual for this

I'm afraid the comment field is far from enough to get even a basic howto. Google for how to patch and compile your own kernel (and modules).
